# Float with Null case condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below code, `IN ELSE`, what if I don't want to pass 'NOTEQUAL' and pass a NULL Value of Float

```
select from table as A {
  A.objek,
  max(case when A.atinn = '0000010530' then  fltp_to_dec( A.atflv as abap.dec(5,3) else <what to enter here for null or no values > end ) as DDC
}
group by A.objek
```

Comment: I don't understand the question here, What do mean if you don't want to pass (the string literal) `'NOTEQUAL'`? You can't compare a `float` to a `varchar` with non-numerical data, and your query isn't parametrised, so you're passing anything.

Comment: Syntax error. You don't select anything, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you need  NULL  then use NULL

```
select from table as A {
  A.objek,
  max(case when A.atinn = '0000010530' 
      then  fltp_to_dec( A.atflv as abap.dec(5,3) 
      else NULL end ) as DDC
}
group by A.objek
```

or nothing as suggested  by Larnu

```
select from table as A {
  A.objek,
  max(case when A.atinn = '0000010530' 
      then  fltp_to_dec( A.atflv as abap.dec(5,3) 
      end ) as DDC
}
group by A.objek
```

Comment: Why not just drop the `ELSE NULL` altogether? A `CASE` expression that doesn't evaluate True for any `WHEN` clauses and doesn't have an `ELSE` returns `NULL` anyway.

Comment: @Larnu  correct answer  updated  .. with your suggestion too